# I'm getting an Actionscript 2048 Security Error, but I don't think it's a crossdomain issue. Could it be something else?

Tags: flash, json, actionscript-3, cross-domain

I'm trying to request to an API method on the same server that is hosting the SWF file. I'm getting a security error 2048. This occurs whether I use POST or GET, and leaving the request data blank doesn't improve things. Nothing is sent in either case, and I get a SecurityErrorEvent to stare at. Everything works smoothly from the IDE.

The applet isn't trying to load the crossdomain.xml file, so it apparently isn't considering the request to be cross-domain, and shouldn't be any other domains involved. Loading images from the swfRoot works fine.

Is there anything else that could be causing this error? Furthermore, is there any way I can find out more details about what exactly is going on? Tracing the toString of the ErrorEvent only gives me "Error 2048" - I've seen reference in other questions to messages for this error that read "cannot load data from XXX", but I can't seem to get one of these (I'm using Flash CS5).

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
var url:String = apiRoot + 'students/'+this.student.id+"/?authorization="+this.student.id+":"+authToken; //this all seems to work fine

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var toSend:Object = foo
request.data = JSON.encode(toSend)
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; //Post is the one the server is expecting, but I get identical issues with GET
loader.load(request);
```

(now fixed - see answer below)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer (where "found" means "paid someone else to find", but still!).

It turned out to be a very strange bug indeed - an issue with how Flash handles relative path - you can read about it [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=267452) from its conqueror!

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in your embed code?

```
attributes.allownetworking = "all";
```

Answer (score 0):

[[Edit]]

Realized the execution wasn't the issue, although I'd still recommend the code below.  If you are testing out side of the IDE, and in the brower, with a local file path, you will need to give your swf permissions through the flash security console.

[Security Console](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html)

Best of luck.

---

I've never used JSON.encode(obj) for the request's data.  I suppose it *could* work, but you should opt for the URLVariables object.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://posttestserver.com/post.php");
var requestVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

requestVariables.key = "value";
request.data = requestVariables;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

loader.load(request);
```

Tested against [Henry's HTTP Post Dumping Server](http://www.posttestserver.com/)